# Pattern or construct to set default values for multiple classes implementing an interface

Tags: typescript, class, design-patterns, interface

I find myself repeating a lot of code, along the lines of:

```js
interface IMyInterface {
  commonA: string;
  commonB: string;
}

class Foo implements IMyInterface {
  commonA: string = "hello";
  commonB: string = "world";
  foo: string = "Foo!";
}

class Bar implements IMyInterface {
  commonA: string = "hello";
  commonB: string = "world";
  bar: string = "Bar!";
}
```

In my case I have numerous classes which all share `commonA` and `commonB` but differ otherwise. Now, I know I can't set default values in the interface, but is there some design pattern or TS construct which will allow me to define the default values in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are not supposed to have default or any values, but you can definitely use **Abstract Class** to achieve this. 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes

```js
interface IMyInterface {
  commonA: string;
  commonB: string;
}

abstract class Base implements IMyInterface {
  commonA: string = "hello";
  commonB: string = "world";
}

class Foo extends Base {
  foo: string = "Foo!";
}

class Bar extends Base {
  bar: string = "Bar!";
}
```

More on difference between abstract classes and interfaces: http://dotnetpattern.com/typescript-abstract-class

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for refreshing OOP 101 ;)